# MS Access Append Query too big

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with a large table of pricing data = EB. I want to append 45 days of pricing data to that table so I have written the query below. The query doesn't seem to run though as I get 2 GB warning and also memory warning. The EB table has 716,580 records in it and I have indexed on Symbol and Date.

Please help as I'm new to this. 
Thanks

```
INSERT INTO EB ( Symbol, Description, [Currency], UNITS, [Date], LOW, HIGH, [CLOSE], INDEX_MIDPOINT, VOLUME, BID, ASK, [OPEN], MEAN )
SELECT EB_hist.Symbol, EB_hist.Description, EB_hist.Currency, EB_hist.UOM, 
EB_hist.Date, EB_hist.[Low(l)], EB_hist.[High(h)], EB_hist.[Close(c)], 
EB_hist.[Index(u)], EB_hist.[Volume(v)], EB_hist.[Bid(b)], EB_hist.[Ask(a)], 
EB_hist.[Open(o)], EB_hist.[Mean(m)]
FROM EB, EB_hist
WHERE (((EB_hist.Date)>(select MAX([Date]) from EB)));
```

Comment: Start by removing all indexes before massive load. You will set up the indexes back afterwards, if you can

Comment: Thanks but the EB data is already loaded and there. So all the query should do is check if the data in EB_hist is in EB and if it is not add it. Surely an index is best for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JOIN clause in the SELECT between EB and EB_hist. This results in a Cartesian relationship (every record of each table is associated with each record of other table) which is probably why the query hits 2GB limit. This is the limit for an entire Access db. Try removing EB from the SELECT (not the SELECT Max() subquery).

Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names. Also, date, close, currency are reserved words, should not use reserved words as names.

Comment: Legend! Thanks very much.